# Focus on breathing vs on heart beats

Tags: meditation

I do yoga and meditation since about two years.

Breathing is a very important according to all books and teachers I met.

During the last days I discovered that there is something with helps me much more than focusing on breathing:

> Focus on your heart beat.

Listening to my heart beat (for example counting the beats) brings me much faster to the easy and relaxed feeling.

Does some know if there are scientific reports which analyse how counting heart beats help you to relax?

.... or what do you think? I guess a lot of readers already did listen to their breathing. How does listening to the heart beats help you to relax?